# How to define multiple c flags in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, c, xcode, flags

In Build settings, at custom compiler Flags, how can i declare two other `C` flags names?

For example:

Other C Flags: `-DEXAMPLE`

I tried:

Other C Flags: `-DEXAMPLE`, `-DEXAMPLE2`

`-DEXAMPLE2` is not working. How can i declare multiple `C` Flags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the comma, each `-D` is its own argument to the compiler:

```
-DEXAMPLE -DEXAMPLE2
```